# dplyr only returning one row when using summarize

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm just getting around to giving dplyr's chain operator a try.

Using the simple example:

```
group_by(mtcars, cyl) %>%
summarise(mean(disp), mean(hp))
```

I get the result:

```
  # mean(disp) mean(hp)
  #1   230.7219 146.6875
```

For some reason dplyr isn't grouping, just summarizing the entire vector. What am I missing?

Comment: It's true for all data.frames, not just mtcars

Comment: I'm using version .3.0.2

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Start a fresh session this is what I get:

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>%
    group_by(cyl) %>%
    summarise(mean(disp), mean(hp))

##   cyl mean(disp)  mean(hp)
## 1   4   105.1364  82.63636
## 2   6   183.3143 122.28571
## 3   8   353.1000 209.21429
```

**Edit**

Don't load `plyr` second (after `dplyr`) or at all.  The problem is that it's using `plyr::summarise` not `dplyr::summarise`:

```
mtcars %>%
    group_by(cyl) %>%
    plyr::summarise(mean(disp), mean(hp))

##   mean(disp) mean(hp)
## 1   230.7219 146.6875
```

**Edit 2**

You could also just be explicit and say which package to pull `sumamrise` from as seen below:

```
mtcars %>%
    group_by(cyl) %>%
    dplyr::summarise(mean(disp), mean(hp))
```

Comment: correct, I was loading plyr as part of my standard set of libraries. Will accept your answer in 9 mins.

Comment: I need `ldply` from `plyr`, is there similar function to avoid loading `plyr`?

Comment: ah, I can detach it after I use the function I need :)

Comment: I didn't import `plyr`. Somehow it was using `plyr`. So, changing to `dplyr::summarize` worked for me.